# CakePHP 3.x における、テーブルを必要としない Model クラスの書き方

Tags: php, cakephp

### 質問の背景

個人的に作成しているサービスで、自作の RESTful API に接続してデータを取得したいと考えています。

APIのエンドポイント例

```
http://example.com/api/restful/v1/profile/{...}
```

---

## 自分で調べてみたこと

CakePHP 3.x では MVC の M (Model) が大幅に変更されたためなのか、まるで情報が見つかりません。
チュートリアルにも `Tableless Model` や `Datasource` に言及したページが見つかりませんでした。

以下、CakePHP 2.x でのチュートリアルページ

- `Datasource` の場合
  CakePHP 2.x では `Datasource` クラスを継承して API への接続を実装できました。
  参考 URL : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/datasources.html
- `Tableless Model` の場合
  Tableless なモデルを用いて API からデータを取得する方法が考えられます。
  参考 URL : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#usetable

どちらの場合でも CakePHP 3.x でやるにはどうしたらいいか資料が見つからず困っております。
どなたかお力添えして頂けると助かります。

Comment: 今まで 外部の API に接続するコードが何となく肥満モデルになりがちだったのですが、`Vendor` に逃がして CakePHP の依存を断ち切り、独立させることもできるわけですね。

今日はよく眠れそうです、ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CakePHP 3 において、`Table` クラスや `Entity` クラスのようなモデルと呼ばれるものは、
ORM を前提としているので、これらを継承して利用するのに DB 以外のデータソースは適切ではありません。

今回の場合は、ORM を利用するのではなく、プレーンな普通のクラスとして定義するとよいと思います。